# Getting a NAT Ip instead of a LAN Ip in VitualBox even after setting a Bridge connection?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, debian

Host machine: Macbook Pro 2012

I have set a bridged network in VB with the following settings

[image]

However I'm still getting a NAT ip instead of LAN ip even after setting a Bridged connection.

However I can still successfully ping google.com

I don't understand how even tho i have already set a bridged connection I'm still getting a NAT IP address.

I have already ran: service network-manager restart, after I changed from NAT to Bridged

but I still get a LAN address

[image]

I have already set NetworkManager.conf to true, and I have already installed the virtual box extension pack.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting "Bridge" mode attaches you directly to the same network the host is on – which means, if the host itself is behind a NAT, the guest will also be. It seems that the setting works fine – you're getting an IPv4 address different from the default VirtualBox NAT ranges, *and* an IPv6 address.

The VirtualBox settings only control VirtualBox's *own* NAT (an additional layer on top of what your real network provides), they can't magically tunnel through external routers.

Comment: So basically I'm not getting a LAN ip because my Host machine is doesn't have one either.

Comment: And this also means that my guest machine and host machine are seen as two totally different entities online ? Meaning that I can't relate my virtual machine to my physical machine

Comment: As far as your next-hop router is concerned, yes, they're two separate computers, with separate IP addreses (although when bridging Wi-Fi they still need to share a single MAC address). Compare the addresses shown by http://ipv6-test.com/ for example.